# A Programm that check if a list of number is Integer or not, and then put it in a a list

Tags: haskell, computer-science, haskell-platform

So I am trying to build a program that receives a list of numbers and checks if they're integer. If the numbers are, put them in a result list. 
I tried something like that but did not work (all the functions works only `mylist`)

```
numberisInteger number = number == fromInteger(round number)

one :: Float -> [Float] 
one x = if numberisInteger x then [x] else [] 

two xs = [one x | x <- xs] 

toint :: [Float] -> [Int] 
toint = roundd

roundd xs = [round x | x <- xs]

mylist xs = [toint x | x <- xs]


main :: IO ()
main = return ()
```

A description of what the code did: `numberisIntger` is function that check if a number integer or not and it gives back true or false, one is function its parameter if its integer then it put it in a list if not it gives an empty one, two function is like one but as a comprehension, `toint` function covert a list of float to int.

Comment: A description of what the code did: numberisIntger is function that check if a number integer or not and it gives back true or false, one is function its parameter if its integer then it put it in a list if not it gives an empty one, two function is like one but as a comprehension, toint function covert a list of float to int.

Comment: Erm, that doesn't explain where _the problem_ is.

Comment: There is some information missing, what is the behaviour you expect? 

I mean, could you please write something like:
* When I run the program, it does ....
* But instead of that, I expect it to do...

Answer (score 2):

Given your function (with `truncate` rather than `round`), it seems that all you need is `filter`:

```hs
isInteger :: RealFrac a => a -> Bool
isInteger x = fromIntegral (truncate x) == x

integers :: RealFrac a => [a] -> [a]
integers = filter isInteger
```

`RealFrac a => a` could be `Float` or `Double`. Since [the rounding functions of `RealFrac`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:RealFrac) don't make further restrictions, neither does this function need to: `a` is some `RealFrac` and `b` is some `Integral`.

Note that if you were using [`Data.Ratio` / `Rational`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html) to express lossless fractional numbers, you'd know that something is an integer when [`denominator`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html#v:denominator) is 1.